# define implicit function in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Hi I want to make plots of implicit functions, e.g.:

```
ContourPlot3D[ {x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 1==0, z == 3}, 
               {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, -10, 10}]
```

This works, but I would prefer to have the functions set up outside of the ContourPlot3D[] command. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Yes, you can define the functions elsewhere.  Have you tried it?  (Sorry, the problem is not clear to me.)

Comment: I tried for example to set up a function like:
f[x_,y_,z_]:= x^2 + y^2 + z^2 and use f in ContourPlot3D[f==0,...]. But that didn't work. I'm quite new to Mathematica, so sorry if my question seems trivial :)

Comment: You need to use `f[x,y,z]==0` instead of `f==0`.

Comment: Thank you that works. My problem is now that I use two additonal parameters for sliders:
f[x_, y_, z_] := (a*(x^2 + y^2) + b*z^2) - 1;
Manipulate[
 ContourPlot3D[ f[x, y, z] == 0, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 
   10}, {z, -10, 10}],
  {a, -0.1, 0.1}, {b, -0.1, 0.1}, {{c, 3}, -5, 5}]

Unfortunately this does not work, I guess because Mathematica does not know a and b before the call of Manipulate[].

Comment: The general way to do this would be to add `a` as a parameter (another argument) to `f`, and use `f[x,y,z,a]`, or if you like `f[a][x,y,z]` ...

Comment: Very nice, thank you again.